# Adding 7 days to an SQL date field after creation using a trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm trying to add 7 days onto a date field once a user has signed up.  I take a number of details from a user on signup including *date_entered*.  It appears in the format *2016-05-01*.  I want to add 7 days to this date automatically so the *next_due* field will be populated with *2016-05-08*.

The table is called '`tasks`' and the two fields are '`date_entered`' and '`next_due`'.

**EDIT:**

Question was marked as a duplicate, but where in the other question does it refer to triggers? I need some advice on creating the trigger so the date updates automatically when a new user is added. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER tasks_BEFORE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON tasks FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.next_due = DATE_ADD(NEW.date_entered, INTERVAL 7 DAY);  
END//
```

**Edited version:**

This trigger prepare your fields before insert to the table, then you can:

1. in your insert statement, pass the value 'frequency"
2. take the frequency from a config table, where this value is a "constant"

Focusing on the first option, imagine the follow situation:

```
insert into tasks('name','date_entered', 'frequency') VALUES('send email','2016-10-02', 25)
```

I put 25 as a frequency. (remember to create the frequency field before)

Then you can adapt the trigger such as:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER tasks_BEFORE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON tasks FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.next_due = DATE_ADD(NEW.date_entered, INTERVAL NEW.frequency DAY);  
END//
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a go

Comment: Works perfectly thank you.  I'm wondering, can it be altered so iit adds a set number of days from another field?  If I had a field called 'frequency', can we add the number of days in frequency rather than the preset 7 days I mentioned before? Cheers

Comment: I edited the answerd to try to help you with the another case

Comment: Superb. Works a treat. Thank you so much

Comment: Fine!, then, could you mark this question as completed? thank you